# Count records using LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count how many bills I have for each status registered. And for those status who don't have a match, show 0.

When I use a `LEFT JOIN` **without** any `WHERE` clause, it works perfectly:

```
SELECT bs.name 'status', count(b.StatusId) 'quantity'
FROM BillStatus bs
LEFT JOIN Bill b on b.StatusID = bs.Id
GROUP BY bs.name
```

[image]

But when I add a WHERE clause, it only shows the status that have a match ('Pendente' status is missing):

```
SELECT bs.name 'status', count(b.StatusId) 'quantity'
FROM BillStatus bs
LEFT JOIN Bill b on b.StatusID = bs.Id
WHERE MONTH(b.RefDate) = 2
AND YEAR(b.RefDate) = 2019
GROUP BY bs.name
```

[image]

How can I show the 'Pendente' status that is missing from the query with the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the clause in the `WHERE` implicitly turns it into an `INNER JOIN`. Also, avoid using functions on your columns in the `ON`/`WHERE` as it can (will) effect performance. Use proper date logic:

```sql
SELECT bs.[name] AS Status,
       COUNT(b.StatusId) AS Quantity
FROM dbo.BillStatus bs
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Bill b ON b.StatusID = bs.Id
                         AND b.RefDate >= '20160301'
                         AND b.RefDate < '20160401';
GROUP BY bs.[name];
```

Also, it's generally best to avoid literal stings for alias names; it can make things difficult to understand. Either use Brackets (`[]`), which are the T-SQL delimit identfier characters, or double quotes (`"`) which are the ANSI ones.

Comment: Understood. Worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the `ON` clause :

```
SELECT bs.name as status, count(b.StatusId) as quantity
FROM BillStatus bs LEFT JOIN 
     Bill b 
     on b.StatusID = bs.Id AND
        MONTH(b.RefDate) = 2 AND 
        YEAR(b.RefDate) = 2019
GROUP BY bs.name;
```

`LEFT JOIN` (table being filtered with) `WHERE` Clause will turn to `INNER JOIN`.

Note :

1. Do not use single quote to represent column name.
2. In SQL Server single quote will represent lateral string.
3. Use brackets `[]` in case space between string.

Comment: Understood. Worked like a charm. Thank you very much.